# How do I install qemu?

Tags: software-installation, virtualization, qemu

How do I install the `qemu` command?

I type `qemu` and press tab and I get a list of several binaries installed.

```
qemu-alpha
qemu-arm
...
qemu-x86_64
```

but no `qemu`.

I type `man qemu` and it returns the docs as if the command is already installed.

I type `qemu` to run the command but it doesn't exist?

```
No command 'qemu' found, did you mean:
 Command 'qtemu' from package 'qtemu' (universe)
 Command 'aqemu' from package 'aqemu' (universe)
qemu: command not found
```

But after installing `sudo apt-get install qtemu aqemu` I'm still unable to run `qemu`.

I'm just attempting to run the following command `qemu -localtime -net user -net nic -m 256 -cdrom minix.iso -hda minix.img -boot d`, for a minix tutorial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am looking for this answer as well. Most forums with info on using qemu give us help for a different version. Whichever version is being installed in the ubuntu repos, it is completely different, works completely differently than the normal qemu.

Comment: Recent versions of Ubuntu (at least 14.04) have a `qemu` symlink that defaults to `qemu-system-i386`. That can be changed with `sudo update-alternatives --config qemu`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just replace `qemu` with `qemu-system-i386` or `qemu-system-x86_64` as appropriate (whether you want a 32-bit or 64-bit system, and which ISO you're using).

You can also use `aqemu`, which is a graphical (GUI) front-end to qemu.

Comment: doesn't work because programs like aqemu are setup to work with qemu but not qemu-arm etc... qemu-launcher wants to call qemu-system-arm but only qemu-arm exists and whatever version of qemu that ubuntu is installing is totally funky and does not work like the normal version . any site I go to with instructions on running qemu from the terminal don't work with ubuntu qemu and qemu-arm etc gives me a help page whenever I try to use it.

Comment: Well... aqemu gives you the command line that it tries to use and you can copy / paste that and change the qemu with the proper emulator. Or if you always use the i386 then create a softlink so qemu starts qemu-system-i386. But in 12.04 the window shell doesn't get resized automatically 8-(

Comment: qemu-system-x86_64 packege can not be located (I am on 14.04)

Answer (score 35):

On [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) I have installed the qemu-system package with:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-system
```

Inside the package it includes:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-cris
/usr/bin/qemu-system-mips64
/usr/bin/qemu-system-mipsel
/usr/bin/qemu-system-sparc
/usr/bin/qemu-system-sparc64
/usr/bin/qemu-system-sh4
/usr/bin/qemu-system-ppc64
/usr/bin/qemu-system-ppc
/usr/bin/qemu-system-m68k
/usr/bin/qemu-system-arm
/usr/bin/qemu-system-ppcemb
/usr/bin/qemu-system-sh4eb
/usr/bin/qemu-system-microblaze
/usr/bin/qemu-system-mips64el
/usr/bin/qemu-system-mips
```

I have executed an ISO image in an i386 machine with:

```
qemu-system-i386 -net user -cdrom my_iso.iso
```

Answer (score 5):

In synaptic package manager you can look for `qemu-system` package and install it. It will install the binaries for all supported architectures.

Answer (score 5):

In `/usr/bin`, there is not `qemu`, but you can use `qemu-system-x86_64`,`qemu-system-arm` , etc.

You can write:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -localtime -net user -net nic -m 256 -cdrom minix.iso -hda minix.img -boot d
```

But if you need to use `qemu`, create a link to `qemu-system-x86_64` in `~/bin/qemu`.

Comment: This does not really add more to the question then the answers already given?